# VS code extension for autocomplete HTML class name in CSS file

Tags: html, css, sass, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a VS code extension for autocomplete HTML class and id names in CSS or SCSS files. There are many extensions for autocomplete CSS class names in HTML file i.e `HTML CSS Support`  but I want autocompletion in CSS files. `PHP Storm IDE` has this built-in feature but I have not found it in VS code yet.
Please let me know if you know anything about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [Beautify css/sass/scss/less](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier)